# How to change VSCode integrated terminal User interface?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, zsh

Currently, I have this VSCode integrated terminal UI. I think this is by default by I changed the default shell to "Zsh":

[image]

I have these settings:

[image]

And I want to change it to something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The prompt that's being showed in your terminal is the **default prompt** with zsh. Now the prompt that you have shown below(the one that you want) is from my guess the [agnoster-zsh-theme prompt](https://github.com/agnoster/agnoster-zsh-theme).

The easiest and effective in long run way to install this theme is by using the **Oh My Zsh(OMZ)** framework for managing your zsh configuration.

Follow this simple [manual installation](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh#manual-installation) guide provided in the OMZ repository. OMZ uses agnoster as the default theme.

You may also have to install a patched/powerline font, which support glyphs and unicode characters, inorder to display all symbols(glyphs) in terminal. I would recommend **Fira Code**. Here is the [installation of Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki#installing-font).

Hope this helps.